# Why is passing a JSON array to a controller action not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

My javascript

```
function SaveData(status) {
    var reserved = [];
    var id = -1;
    $('#fdEitDetail').find('table tr').each(function (index, item) {
        var isChk = $(item).find('input:checkbox').is(':checked') ? 0 : 1;
        id = $(item).attr('name');
        reserved.push({ ID: $(item).attr('id'), IsChecked: isChk, Comment: $(item).find('textarea').val() });
    });

    var dataset = JSON.stringify({ checkList: reserved, status: status, machineID: id });
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/UpdateData',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataset,
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
}
```

I am calling this controller action:

```
public JsonResult UpdateData(string checkList, int status,int machineID)
{
    var response = 
        new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<PMICheckListRequest>>(checkList);

    return Json("value = Success");
}
```

the class

```
public class PMICheckListRequest
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int IsChecked { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller action is being hit from the ajax request both of this `parameterstatus`, `machineID` has the value that i set in javascript but `checkList` is `null` always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the `checkList` parameter is `null` it is because you are trying to bind a complex object JSON array (i.e `[{}, {}]`) to a `string`, when the types aren't really compatible.

Try this instead,

```
public JsonResult UpdateData(
    List<PMICheckListRequest> checkList, 
    int status, 
    int machineID)
{
    return Json("value = Success");
}
```

You do not have to deserialize it manually; the model binder will do that for you.

As a extra note, it is not a bad idea to create a view model to hold the data in a more organized way, the way @DarinDimitrov shows,

```
public JsonResult UpdateData(
    PMICheckListRequestViewModel model)
{
    return Json("value = Success");
}

...

public class PMICheckListRequestViewModel
{
    public List<PMICheckListRequest> CheckList { get; set; }

    public int Status { get; set; }

    public int MachineID { get; set; }
}
```

It will prove more flexible in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a view model and stop hanging around those strings that you need to be parsing:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public PMICheckListRequest[] CheckList { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public int MachineID { get; set; }
}
```

as parameter to your controller action:

```
public ActionResult UpdateData(MyViewModel)
{
    // NO NEED TO BE DOING ANY PLUMBING DESERIALIZATION HERE
    // THE VIEW MODEL ALREADY CONTAINS EVERYTHING YOU NEED

    return Json("value = Success");
}
```

Notice how the view model already contains an array of `PMICheckListRequest` where each element has properties `ID`, `IsChecked` and `Comment` which you already populate in the AJAX request.